# Why in some WebI reports Exporting Excel not happening

Tags: crystal-reports, report, business-intelligence, business-objects

I have 5 Webi reports and all these reports works fine. Out of the 5 reports, 3 reports I could export to available mode. But the other 2 reports too I can export to PDF or Excel or Excel 2007. Here comes the problem. When I export to excel or excel 2007, I do not get the exact structure of the report, like the table and the values. What I get is complete blank with Report Tab name.

Have anyone gone through this kind of problem? If so please help me if I went wrong for this 2 reports alone.

Thanks
Niki.

Comment: can you try to schedule these reports to excel and see if you see any data there. This way we can start narrowing down the issue.

Comment: @VB1: still the same..not getting exact structure as well as data.

Comment: I'm assuming I have the same issue with this. I have a very large amount of data that I'm attempting to export to a simple XLSX file (one table with around 250k rows in it). Once it's exported, the file is blank other than the header row. It also happens when trying to export to CSV file, where the archive is created, the csv file inside is created, but no data is in there.)

Answer (score 0):

First select the Table and Check in Vertical Table setting and if you see any Blank variable added into report, please delete.

So that report will extract without any error.

Answer (score -1):

You can set preferences if you want to optimise export to Excel to preserve formatting or preserve data.  Try configuring your preferences to preserve data or preserve formatting when exporting to excel and experiment.

Exporting to excel can be tedious, your webi report needs to be optimised to properly export to excel and preserve formatting and data

Comment: This option was done but unfortunately that could not resolve my issue and the option i had to choose was to recreate the report.